# How can I send an Html.HiddenFor value as a parameter in an onchange event?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I’m trying to send a parameter to an action using a dropdown list and onchange.  I’ve tried sending a hard-coded value like this:

onchange = "this.form.action='/Profile/Edit/16

That  works fine but now I want to send the value from a hidden id found here:

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.StudentID)

…doing something like this:

```
            @Html.DropDownList("DropDownValue", new SelectList(ViewBag.sellectedSubjects, "text"), "select one", new { onchange = "this.form.action='/Profile/Edit/@model => model.StudentID';this.form.method='get';this.form.submit();" })
```

When I do this I get a ‘Bad Request’ error.  How can I send the value in my Html.HiddenFor as a parameter in onchange?  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
        @Html.DropDownList("DropDownValue", new SelectList(ViewBag.sellectedSubjects, "text"), "select one", new { onchange = "this.form.action='/Profile/Edit/"+Model.StudentID+"';this.form.method='get';this.form.submit();" })
```

Comment: Thanks the error is gone but the program doesn’t stop at the breakpoint that I have set in this.form.action='/Profile/Edit/.

Could I be using a wrong post to the Profile/Edit action?

Comment: Actually you should use something like firebug or fiddler to check what request is going and where? If you don't know how to use them to inspect, leave a message here and I will guide you through it.

Comment: I'm sorry I've never use firebug or fiddler. Can you please show me?

Comment: Ok. First of all, to troubleshoot can you tell me the url which is shown in browser's address bar after the form is submitted via dropdownlist? And is it the correct url that you wanted?

Comment: Here’s a portion the url.  It does have the value that I want:
http://localhost:11111/Profile/Edit/25?StudentID=25&courseTitle=&LastName=.....

Comment: Ok got it.. so have you put some filter on your action edit like [HttpPost] or [HttpGet] because I think everything else is fine. If it's there then try commenting it out to check if the action is being hit now.